# How to iterate through a Django ManyToManyField in a sorted order?

Tags: python, django, django-models, manytomanyfield

I have the following 2 Django models:

```
from django.db import models

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=255)
    b = models.ManyToManyField(B, related_name="A_b")
```

I create the following instances:

```
p = B.objects.create(name="P")
q = B.objects.create(name="Q")
r = B.objects.create(name="R")
f = A.objects.create(name="F")
f.add(r)
f.add(q)
f.add(p)
f.save()
```

Now, when I do iterate through the `Bs` on `f`, I get the following:

```
>>> [i for i in f.b.iterator()]
['R', 'Q', 'P']
```

How do I iterate through the `B` objects associated with `f` such that they appear in alphabetically sorted order??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there are other approaches but what I usually do is to take advantage of the [model `Meta.ordering`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/options/#ordering) like:

```
class B(CachingMixin, MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks. I will accept the answer as soon as it lets me. :)

Answer (score 3):

Related objects are querysets. So you can order by any field you like:

```
f.b.order_by('name')
```

Comment: BTW Daniel, I didn't know one could add directly to the object `f.add(r)` bypassing the field `f.b.add(r)`. Is that correct? And I'd never seen `.iterator()` either